# Coolant level drop in new Bajaj Dominar 2019 UG

Tags: motorcycle, coolant, coolant-leak, bajaj

In **Bajaj Dominar 2019 UG**, the **coolant level** was a little below midline between min and max when it was purchased but after running around 200 Kms, I noticed that it's at Min level now. Though it increases slightly after the bike is ridden for some time. Is this drop in coolant level normal for a new bike? My first service is after another 250 Kms run, so should I just get the coolant refilled for now or should I report this to the service centre?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very well could have had an air pocket which finally worked its way out. That would drop the coolant level a little. I'd see nothing wrong with adding a bit of 50/50 mix to top it off ... just pay attention to your owners manual as to what type of coolant you should be using. If you need to, call the dealership maintenance department. They can tell you *exactly* what you should be using.